# Calculate Price Depending on Season (Dates) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, diff, utc

we would like to calculate seasonal prices based on Months via JavaScript.

Expected Return will be array with following details.

```
Total Days;
Total Cost;
Days from Jan;
Days from Feb;
Days from Mar;
Days from Apr;
Days from May;
Days from June;
...
```

It may continue as Days from July, Days from August, Days from September

[trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47401063/2511969)'s answer is pretty nice idea but not arranged for this. Is it possible to extend the code as expected array?

Thank you from advance.

```js
    // Utility function to facilitate day counting without timezone issues:
    const dayNumber = a => Date.UTC(a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate()) / (24*60*60*1000);

    function getPrices(allSeasons, arrival, departure) {
        return allSeasons.reduce( (totalPrice, {startDate, endDate, costRate}) => {
            let daysInSeason = Math.min(dayNumber(endDate) + 1, dayNumber(departure)) 
                             - Math.max(dayNumber(startDate), dayNumber(arrival));
            return totalPrice + (daysInSeason > 0 && daysInSeason * costRate);
        }, 0);
    } 

    const allSeasons = [
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 1-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 1, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 2-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 2, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 3-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 3, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 4-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 4, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 5-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 5, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 6-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 6, 0), costRate: 8000},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 7-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 7, 0), costRate: 9000},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 8-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 8, 0), costRate: 9000},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 9-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 9, 0), costRate: 8000},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 10-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 10, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 11-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 11, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2022, 12-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2022, 12, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 1-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 1, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 2-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 2, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 3-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 3, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 4-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 4, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 5-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 5, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 6-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 6, 0), costRate: 8000},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 7-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 7, 0), costRate: 9000},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 8-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 8, 0), costRate: 9000},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 9-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 9, 0), costRate: 8000},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 10-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 10, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 11-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 11, 0), costRate: 6500},
        {startDate: new Date(2023, 12-1, 1), endDate: new Date(2023, 12, 0), costRate: 6500},
    ],

    embarkation0 = new Date(2022, 6-1, 18),
    disembarkation0 = new Date(2022, 6-1, 25),
    totalPrice0 = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation0, disembarkation0);

    console.log('7x8.000 (18,19,20,21,22,23,24) Should be 56.000 = ' + totalPrice0); 
    
    embarkation1 = new Date(2022, 6-1, 25),
    disembarkation1 = new Date(2022, 7-1, 02),
    totalPrice1 = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation1, disembarkation1);

    console.log('6x8.000 (25,26,27,28,29,30) + 1x9.000 (01) Should be 57.000 instead of ' + totalPrice1); 

    embarkation2 = new Date(2022, 8-1, 20),
    disembarkation2 = new Date(2022, 8-1, 27),
    totalPrice2 = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation2, disembarkation2);

    console.log('7x9.000 (20,21,22,23,24,25,26) Should be 63.000 = ' + totalPrice2); 

    embarkation3 = new Date(2022, 8-1, 27),
    disembarkation3 = new Date(2022, 9-1, 03),
    totalPrice3 = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation3, disembarkation3);

    console.log('5x9.000 (27,28,29,30,31) + 2x8.000 (01,02) Should be 61.000 instead of ' + totalPrice3); 

    embarkation4 = new Date(2022, 9-1, 24),
    disembarkation4 = new Date(2022, 10-1, 01),
    totalPrice4 = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation4, disembarkation4);

    console.log('7x8.000 (24,25,26,27,28,29,30) Should be 56.000 instead of ' + totalPrice4); 
    
    embarkation5 = new Date(2023, 8-1, 26),
    disembarkation5 = new Date(2023, 9-1, 02),
    totalPrice5 = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation5, disembarkation5);

    console.log('6x9.000 (26,27,28,29,30,31) + 1x8.000 (01) Should be 62.000 instead of ' + totalPrice5); 
    
    embarkation6 = new Date(2024, 8-1, 28),
    disembarkation6 = new Date(2024, 9-1, 05),
    totalPrice6 = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation6, disembarkation6);

    console.log('Non Exist Value 3x9.000 (28,29,30) + 4x8.000 (01,02,03,04) Should be 59.000 instead of ' + totalPrice6);
```

Comment: *"If there is no definition as dates range (even not exist for early year),"*: I don't understand this rule. Can you edit your question and provide concrete examples of missing periods and dates, and corresponding expected price?

Comment: trincot is it convenient?

Comment: But what if a season crosses the year boundary, will it still be candidate for lowest price? I find it a bit strange that the rule changes from "earlier" to "minimum" when there is no earlier. What if that year does not have prices, would you then need to take the minimum from the first year that has prices? Why not just the "next" price instead of "minimum"?

Comment: @trincot actually we do not use years but months. Prices are calculating based on months (3 seasons as highseason, midseason, lowseason) so year is not important. As an example "July", "August" is 30k , "September", "June" is 20k other months 10k... As an example 27 August - 03 September 2022 should be calculated as 5 days from the August 2 days from the september as 5x30k (August) + 2x30k (September) as we calculate from embarkation date as 1 full day. (Disembarkation date is not calculated.)

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't answer the question on boundary cases where the year is empty, where periods are multiple months and cross years, ...etc, ...etc. I still don't understand how the scope of where to take the "minimum" from will always be clearly defined. Again, why the minimum-rule? It seems out of line with the previous-rule.

Comment: @trincot would you please check our current solution from the last snipped.

Comment: The question becomes too broad: we currently have these questions: (1) how to improve related to UTC? (2) how to deal with gaps? (3) can you review my code? A question on Stack Overflow should be just one question. Also, if you have working code, and want it to be reviewed, then consider [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). For the daylight saving issue that could come up, I prefer to edit my 2017 answer, which I have done in the mean time. BTW, in your question the link to my answer is not correct.

Comment: @trincot really sorry for that. I updated the questions with your comments. Meanwhile there is something wrong with calculation because now it calculates 30.July - 06 August as 54.000 instead of 63.000, if you have still patient are there any chance to check.

Comment: @trincot
It seems code does not correctly work with month boundaries.
I updated the question with more examples

Comment: But what are those -1 dates? That will not resolve to the last day of the previous month, but to the one-but-last day of the previous month. The last day of the previous month needs a 0, not -1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249710/discussion-between-trincot-and-deniz-porsuk).

Comment: I think there are two errors in the examples you have put in your code. 7*8.000 is 56.000, but you expect 63.000. The last test doesn't account for 31 August.

Comment: First test explanation Updated. Last test was to show it was not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your seasons correspond to calendar months, I would propose to use a simpler data structure: an array per year, each with 12 prices, one for each month in that year.

The code could be as follows:

```js
// Utility functions
const dateParts = a => [a.getFullYear(), a.getMonth(), a.getDate()];
const daysInMonth = (year, month) => new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();

function getPrices(allSeasons, arrival, departure) {
    let [year, month, day] = dateParts(arrival);
    let [year2, month2, day2] = dateParts(departure);
    let totalPrice = 0, totalDays = 0;
    const monthDays = Array(12).fill(0);
    for (let diff = year2*12 + month2 - (year*12 + month); diff >= 0; diff--) {
        const price = (allSeasons[year] ?? Object.values(allSeasons).at(-1))[month];
        const days = (diff ? daysInMonth(year, month) + 1 : day2) - day;
        totalPrice += price * days;
        totalDays += days;
        monthDays[month] += days;
        day = 1;
        month = (month + 1) % 12;
        year += !month;
    }
    return [totalDays, totalPrice, ...monthDays];
}

const allSeasons = {
    2022: [6500, 6500, 6500, 6500, 6500, 8000, 9000, 9000, 8000, 6500, 6500, 6500],
    2023: [6500, 6500, 6500, 6500, 6500, 8000, 9000, 9000, 8000, 6500, 6500, 6500],
};

function test(embarkation, disembarkation, expected, msg) {
    let details = getPrices(allSeasons, embarkation, disembarkation);
    console.log(...details);
    if (details[1] !== expected) {
        console.log(msg, "Expected", expected, "but got", totalPrice);
    }
}

test(new Date(2022, 6-1, 18), new Date(2022, 6-1, 25), 56000, '7x8.000 (18,19,20,21,22,23,24)'); 
test(new Date(2022, 6-1, 25), new Date(2022, 7-1, 2), 57000, '6x8.000 (25,26,27,28,29,30) + 1x9.000 (01)'); 
test(new Date(2022, 8-1, 20), new Date(2022, 8-1, 27), 63000, '7x9.000 (20,21,22,23,24,25,26)');
test(new Date(2022, 8-1, 27), new Date(2022, 9-1, 3), 61000, '5x9.000 (27,28,29,30,31) + 2x8.000 (01,02)'); 
test(new Date(2022, 9-1, 24), new Date(2022, 10-1, 1), 56000, '7x8.000 (24,25,26,27,28,29,30)'); 
test(new Date(2023, 8-1, 26), new Date(2023, 9-1, 2), 62000, '6x9.000 (26,27,28,29,30,31) + 1x8.000 (01)'); 
test(new Date(2024, 8-1, 28), new Date(2024, 9-1, 5), 68000, 'Non Exist Value 4x9.000 (28,29,30,31) + 4x8.000 (01,02,03,04)');
console.log("tests completed");
```

Comment: Although it is to hard to understand. This code is **piece of art**. Is it to hard to provide expected details with array?

Comment: Which details are you referring to? You mean the strings like '7x8.000 (18,19,20,21,22,23,24)'?

Comment: Total Days;
Total Cost;
Days from Jan;
Days from Feb;
Days from Mar;
Days from Apr;
Days from May;
Days from June...

Comment: But then you need to also specify the years that are involved?

Comment: Well, I updated the answer with array output. Just realise that if a period is long enough to span the same month twice (e.g. Jan 2022 and Jan 2023), those days will be added together in the slot for January.

Comment: Hey @trincot this is great answer, and working perfectly. Meanwhile would you please correct vote of the question. Thanks.